# problems instalando Roo Addon Suite con GVNIX

Tags: gvnix

Estoy presentando problemas a la hora de instalar la Roo Addon Suite

cuando escribo el comando

```
roo> addon suite list --repository http://repository.gvnix.org/index.xml
```

se muestra

> 1 Roo Addon Suites were found on
>   'http://repository.gvnix.org/index.xml’ repository

pero cuando voy a instalar

```
roo> addon suite install name --symbolicName org.gvnix.roo.addon.suite
```

sale lo siguiente

> Subsystem dependency manager started. Getting 'Roo Addon Suite'
>   dependencies...
>       **0 dependencies were found on selected 'Roo Addon Suite' Subsystem dependency manager finished. Installing subsystem... Unable
>   to find subsystem 0**

No consigo instalarlo y me hace falta desarrollar una solución rápido

Comment: Describe tu entorno: versiones de Spring Roo y de gvNIX, sistema operativo, JVM, et.c

Comment: spring-roo-2.0.0.M2, gvNIX 2.0.0.M1, Sistema Operativo macOS SIERRA, JVM 1.8. Gracias por responder

Comment: STS o línea de comandos? Si STS, indica versión

Comment: es la linea de comandos, pero agradecería si también dices como es con la STS que es la 3.8.2.

Comment: En principio gvNIX 2.0.0.M1 no está actualizado a la versión Spring Roo 2.0.0.M2, por lo que podría no funcionar. Si necesitas gvNIX 2.0.0.M1 prueba a utilizar Spring Roo 2.0.0.M1.